# Is there a way in LINQ to use the group by syntax with a list as a parameter in the group by clause?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an application that helps with the management of learners doing qualifications. We have recently upgraded our systems to simulate classrooms. I need to write a piece of code that will group learners by their classrooms which will include the centre that they are registered to, the qualification they are doing and the units that they are completing. I have tried the below code sample:

```
var midFlightLearners = _learnerRepository.GetAllMidFlightLearners();

var groupedMidFlightLearners = midFlightLearners.GroupBy(l => new
        {
            l.DeliveryCentreId,
            l.QualificationId,
            l.LearnerUnits.Select(lu => lru.Unit).ToList()
        });
```

However this doesn't work as expected. When creating the classrooms the learners need to be grouped by the units that they are taking. Is there any way that this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

.NET BCL does not provide custom comparer for lists by default (i.e. default one - by reference is used, `ToList()` will produce a new list instance, so all the keys will be different, hence you will have groups of one elements). You need either to use some custom type for key which either will implement `Equals+GetHashcode` or pass `IEqualityComparer` to the `GroupBy` call.

Alternatively you can try turning your unit list into string:

```
var groupedMidFlightLearners = midFlightLearners.GroupBy(l => new
{
   //...
   // use some "valid" delimeter
   LearnerUnits = string.Join("|||", l.LearnerUnits.Select(lu => lru.Unit).Order()) // or OrderBy(x => x)
});
```

Comment: The BCL provides `ImmutableArray<T>`, which has value equality semantics. `from learner in midFlightLearners group learner by ImmutableArray.Create(from lru in learner.LearnerUnits order by lru.Unit descending select lru.Unit)`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad can you please show the example. It does not work for me - [@sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0AwgPYA2pApgMbACWxUAzvgJIC2bEwAhgEaUBudOgBu3MNlocufSgEEwYbgE9sAXmztOPfhQVLlRMBW7AKACgBEARwDuFSwBpslxt0sBKIWjETiwAAsKCQ0tGV19FSMTMys7B2dXdy9RcWwKawhuUkZ1SWkdeUUogFFM7MZzfyCwFJ804gAHMrypbVk9YtU1DWrg719061aCjsjlAG1MAF11XsDgqdmAMmX89oiuiaRZnuw+sG3p7zwATnMMrJy6s6rm6xukc4yvIA)

Comment: @AluanHaddad also see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77183).

Comment: Sorry about that I should have tested it. I wasn't expecting deep equality but the behavior outlined in that issue is 99.9% pointless and 100% confusing.

Comment: I understand they didn't want to break dependents but this API should be deprecated. From The Source code, even create 2 IAs from the references to the same underlying array, they will not be considered equal. Sorry for ranting...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ToList` anyway in the middle of a query, as that requires bringing all the data back to the client.

You can use string aggregation to get a single value containing all units.

This is not 100% reliable, as the ordering may differ by row. You could add `.Order()`, but I'm not sure if EF Core can translate that to `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY` correctly.

```cs
var midFlightLearners = _learnerRepository.GetAllMidFlightLearners();

var groupedMidFlightLearners = midFlightLearners
    .Select(l => new {
        l, 
        Units = string.Join(",", l.LearnerUnits.Select(lu => lru.Unit) /* .Order() */ ),
    })
    .GroupBy(l => new
    {
        l.DeliveryCentreId,
        l.QualificationId,
        l.Units,
    });
```

Comment: `GetAllMidFlightLearners()` is probably returning an in-memory collection, not an `IQueryable`. It should be anyway, considering it's a repository method.